# Getting a nested function's argument from its execution environment

Tags: r

Consider the following example:

```
my_function <- function(...){
  x <- 10
  sum(...)
}

my_function(x)
```

I would like to be able to perform this sort of operation, but `my_function` will search from its enclosing environment for `x`, which it won't find.

Any ideas how I could make this work?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? This really messes with the way most R functions work and would lead to odd behavior. Do you maybe just want to set a default parameter value for your function? What's the problem you're really trying to solve that you've determined this to be the solution for?

Comment: Appreciate the warning. Truthfully - not 100% I want to do this but would like to explore the option. The wider problem is that I'm working with the dplyr package. I would like to write a set of functions which could draw upon an attribute of a dataframe which I set, with these functions to be called from within `summarise`. This isn't the cleanest way of achieving what I'd like, but at least may get me to test the concept!

Comment: Well, if you are going to be working with dplyr then you probably want to look at passing quosures or `expr()` objects (use that new `rlang` stuff). That would make life a lot easier. But again that's pretty specific to a `dplyr()` application. And probably still better to have the functions defined outside the function anyway.

Comment: Documents explaining the rlang stuff  rpubs.com/lionel-/programming-draft or  dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but I'm not sure if it's the "right" way of doing it

```
my_function <- function(...){
  x <- 10
  y <- 5
  inn <- substitute(...)
  sum(eval(inn))
}
x <- 2
y <- 3
my_function(c(x, y))

# [1] 15
```

Depending on what you're actually trying to do, your goal might be accomplished by just creating a list and using `with` e.g.

```
vars <- list(x = 10, y = c(80, 44), z = matrix(runif(100), 10))

with(vars, x + y[2] + z[10, 3])

# [1] 54.32984
```